# Git push style deployment for local IIS webserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, iis, deployment

I am looking for a gis push style deployment for my ASP.NET MVC webapps running on a Windows+IIS server. This is the same as Heroku and AppHarbor deal with deployment, but I would like to apply it for my own servers.

In very short, I would like to do the following:

- I made changes to my asp.net mvc site
- When the change is tested than I push it to my git repository deployment branch
- Somewhere a windows server with iis watching this git repository and notices the change
- it pulls the latest source, builds and installs the website
- the IIS webserver is restarted and after restart it runs the latest version of my website.

Is there any library or script collection that would do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Kudu engine](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) powering [Windows Azure git push deployments](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2012/06/introducing-open-source-engine-behind.html) is open source. You should be able to use it for your needs.